pandoc classic filter's template setting
I'm trying to recover, before trying to rewrite, a "classic" pandoc custom writer called tba.lua.
Thus far, I've managed to make it work by adding the prescribed patch in the form
function Writer (doc, opts)
  PANDOC_DOCUMENT = doc
  PANDOC_WRITER_OPTIONS = opts
  loadfile(PANDOC_SCRIPT_FILE)()
  return pandoc.write_classic(doc, opts)
end

as stated in the documentation.
But then, I need to add always a --template option to load the default template, as the writer with the --standalone option complains about
No template defined in tba.lua

While seeing another example in the documentation, I tried to define the template in the writer by adding
function Template ()
 local template = pandoc.template
 return template.compile(template.default 'tba.lua')
end

Pandoc can now find the template default.tba.lua in the --data-dir directory, but now it complains saying
Error running Lua:
string expected, got pandoc Template

I thought that template.compile would return the string and feed it to Pandoc, so I don't know what went wrong.

This was a documentation bug: pandoc used to expect a compiled template as the Template parameter, but that was changed for various reasons. The documentation was updated to reflect this 5 days ago. It will be online after the next pandoc release.
Long story short, the below should work:
Template = pandoc.template.default 'tba.lua'

